# Is there a general way to show that a polynomial is (not) irreducible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials

The assignment states to check whether a given polynomial is irreducible over a given field.

One of them was
$x^3+8x^2+12x+11$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{13}[x]$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ is the ring of the integers modulo $13$.
Is there any way to reliably find the solution? I found it simply by checking whether the polynomial is zero for any $0 \leq x \lt 13$ via brute-force, since the given polynomial is of degree $3$ and as such can be written as $(x+a)(x^2+bx+c)$ if it is not irreducible.

At $x = 8$ there is a zero, so the given polynomial is not irreducible.

However, this feels both inefficient and unelegant, so I am wondering if there is any way to reliably find the answer for any such question.

Comment: There are some simple rules like this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion      But it would not help you here.

Comment: There is an algorithm invented by Kronecker, but it is very cumbersome. If a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ , in most cases this can be shown by the various sufficient conditions, but there is no general method doing the job for every such polynomial.